# Question about the tense of "until ..." in a object clause

Tags: tense, verbs, modal-verbs, future-tense, future-time

Quite confused about it. Here is a sentence:

- I was wondering if you could lend me a few dollars until I ***get*** paid on Friday.

Why is ***got*** or ***would get*** improper here?

Compared with:

- I said I ***would*** go there tomorrow. (Would, not will)
- If you ***go*** there tomorrow, I will lend you some money. (Go, not will go)

Should I say:

- He said that he would not be able to talk until he ***gets*** his microphone tomorrow.
  And
- He said that he would not be able to talk until he ***got*** his microphone the next day.

Please tell me if I'm wrong and why it is so, Thx.

Comment: If the first sentence is direct speech and you are speaking on say Monday, before getting paid, it has to be *get*. Either *get* or *got* could be used if it was counterfactual (*I had been wondering if he could lend me a few dollars before I got paid this Friday, but I've heard he's broke*). If Friday is in the past, it has to be *got* (*why did you come over that day?* *I was wondering if you could lend me a few dollars until I got paid on Friday*).

Comment: The same applies to your last two sentences, except that these are reported speech, which means you can use *got* instead of *get* even if he hasn't yet got the mic.

Comment: @Minty Thanks a lot. I think I've understood your explanation. Indeed, I used to believe this law (using *got* instead of *get*) on reported speech is also correct in any object clause. But it seems that I'm totally wrong. ;P